# How to check if a file is locked or not?

Tags: c, file, locking, fcntl

I have the following code where I want to check if the file is locked or not. If not then I want to write to it. I am running this code by running them simultaneously on two terminals but I always get "locked" status every time in both tabs even though I haven't locked it. The code is below:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    struct flock fl,fl2;
    int fd;

    fl.l_type   = F_WRLCK;  /* read/write lock */
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET; /* beginning of file */
    fl.l_start  = 0;        /* offset from l_whence */
    fl.l_len    = 0;        /* length, 0 = to EOF */
    fl.l_pid    = getpid(); /* PID */

    fd = open("locked_file", O_RDWR | O_EXCL | O_CREAT);
    fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &fl2);
    if(fl2.l_type!=F_UNLCK)
    {
        printf("locked");
    }
    else
    {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl); /* set lock */
        write(fd,"hello",5);
        usleep(10000000);
    }
    printf("\n release lock \n");

    fl.l_type   = F_UNLCK;
    fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl); /* unset lock */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple, just run fnctl with F_GETLK instead of F_SETLK. That will set the data at your pointer to the current state of the lock, you can look up if it is locked then by accessing the l_type property.

please see: http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl for details.

Comment: but `F_GETLK` is already set in the posted code, and the original post is not edited. can you explain the answer a bit. I can't imagine why this answer is accepted? is there something i didn't noticed??

Comment: @Anubis I think it was accepted, because OP found the answer in the above link. I left my own answer explaining what I found to be wrong with the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to `fl2` to be `memset` to 0. Otherwise when you use `fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &fl2)` and `perror` on failure, you will see a message as such on the terminal:

> fcntl: Invalid Arguement

I recomend that you use `perror`, when debugging system calls.